# How save session storage in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i want to create data to all the application

```
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
    public class Session 
        {
        void btnLoginClick()
                {
                    NombreUsuario = Username.Text;
                    Application.Current.Properties["name"] = NombreUsuario;
                    Application.Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"] = true;
        }
    }
```

i have this error

'MediaTypeNames.Application' does not contain a definition for 'Current'

My app:

```
namespace Dinamic.Trailer.Mobile.Forms
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Locator.ConfigureIoC();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override async void OnStart()
        {
            await InitNavigation();
        } 
        //onsleep()//OnStart
        private Task InitNavigation()
        {
            var navigationService = Content.Resolve<MainNavigation>();
            return navigationService.InitializeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the whole class where you have this method

Comment: @Greggz i dont have almost nothing

Comment: Ok. Show me your App.cs

Comment: `MediaTypeNames` this is not your namespace for the App.cs

Comment: Show me the `using's` you have in Session

Comment: @Greggz i dont have nothhing of using's

Comment: When you do `Application.` what properties does the intelisense suggest ?

Comment: i am using using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;, the suggest is soap, xml, zip but i get this errror 'MediaTypeNames.Application' does not contain a definition for 'Current'

Comment: Ofc that is not the `Application` you want. Pls use `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line

`using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;`

And use import the `using Xamarin.Forms;`

After that you can use `Application.Current.Properties["key"] = value;`

Comment: i get error Using directive is unnecessary. The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try it without, there's the possibility the reference is infered

Comment: one delete the using i get The name 'Xamarin' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Remove the usings and try just `Application.Current.Properties["key"] = value;`

Comment: this work in xamarinForms? or IOS? or android, i am getting the wrong yet

Comment: Ofc it works but only inside the shared solution ofc. It won't work in your Android or IOS specific projects

Comment: I still have the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209792/discussion-between-greggz-and-mikkylekyle).

Answer (score 0):

Use **using xamarin.forms** namespace while you use Application.Current.Properties for storing data. Either you could use App.Current.Properties if you do not want to add **xamarin.forms** namespace in your cs file.

Here **App** refer your App class in App.xaml.cs which inherit from Xamarin.forms.Application. so you can use **App.Current.Properties** instead **Application.Current.Properties**.

Thank you.